# How can I inject with resolve async data to a ui bootstrap modal in angular?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

How can I inject with resolve async data to a ui bootstrap modal in angular?
The following code is the controller that opens the modal.

```
import insertOpportunityModal from './insertOpportunityModal.html';

export default class OpportunitiesCtrl {

  constructor($uibModal, OpportunitiesService, EngagementsService, PAGE_SIZE) {
    this.$uibModal = $uibModal;
    this.OpportunitiesService = OpportunitiesService;
    this.EngagementsService = EngagementsService;
  }

  openInsertModal() {
    var modalInstance = this.$uibModal.open({
      animation: false,
      size: 'md', //['lg', 'md', 'sm']
      template: insertOpportunityModal,
      controller: 'InsertOpportunityModalCtrl',
      controllerAs: 'vm',
      resolve: {
        opportunityTypes: function (EngagementsService) {
          return EngagementsService.all();
        }
      }
    });

    modalInstance.rendered.then(() => {
    });

    modalInstance.result.then(() => {
      console.log('modal closed');
    }, (error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });
  }

}

OpportunitiesCtrl.$inject = ['$uibModal', 'OpportunitiesService', 'EngagementsService', 'PAGE_SIZE'];
```

opportunityTypes is undefined in the modal controller.
It works with sync data but not with promises.
How can fix?

```
export default class InsertOpportunityModalCtrl {

  constructor($uibModalInstance, OpportunitiesService, opportunityTypes) {
    this.$uibModalInstance = $uibModalInstance;
    this.OpportunitiesService = OpportunitiesService;
    this.opportunityTypes = opportunityTypes;
    console.log('opportunityTypes', opportunityTypes);
  }

  save() {
  }

  cancel() {
    this.$uibModalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
  }

}

InsertOpportunityModalCtrl.$inject = ['$uibModalInstance', 'OpportunitiesService'];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to inject `opportunityTypes` in `InsertOpportunityModalCtrl` too.

```
InsertOpportunityModalCtrl.$inject = 
    ['$uibModalInstance', 'OpportunitiesService', 'opportunityTypes'];
```